# Mockito mock all methods call and return

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a problem when writing unit testing with mock. There is a object which I need to mock have a lot getter, which I do call them at the code. However, those are not the purpose of my unit test. So, is there is a way I can mock all the methods instead of mock them one by one.

Here is the code example:

```
public class ObjectNeedToMock{

private String field1;
...
private String field20;

private int theImportantInt;


public String getField1(){return this.field1;}
...

public String getField20(){return this.field20;}

public int getTheImportantInt(){return this.theImportantInt;}

}
```

and this is the service class I need to test

```
public class Service{

public void methodNeedToTest(ObjectNeedToMock objectNeedToMock){
    String stringThatIdontCare1 = objectNeedToMock.getField1();
    ...
    String stringThatIdontCare20 = objectNeedToMock.getField20();
    // do something with the field1 to field20

    int veryImportantInt = objectNeedToMock.getTheImportantInt();
    // do something with the veryImportantInt

    }
}
```

within the test class, the test method is like

```
@Test
public void testMethodNeedToTest() throws Exception {
      ObjectNeedToMock o = mock(ObjectNeedToMock.class);
      when(o.getField1()).thenReturn(anyString());
      ....
      when(o.getField20()).thenReturn(anyString());

      when(o.getTheImportantInt()).thenReturn("1"); //This "1" is the only thing I care

}
```

So, is there a way that I can avoid writing all the "when" for the useless "field1" to "field20"

Comment: You don't have to if you're fine with returning them null.

Comment: I do need to use them in the method, sorry for not put this in the example.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can control the default answers of your mock. When you're creating the mock, use:

```
Mockito.mock(ObjectNeedToMock.class, new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        /* 
           Put your default answer logic here.
           It should be based on type of arguments you consume and the type of arguments you return.
           i.e.
        */
        if (String.class.equals(invocation.getMethod().getReturnType())) {
            return "This is my default answer for all methods that returns string";
        } else {
            return RETURNS_DEFAULTS.answer(invocation);
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your answer correctly. I still need to manually set default value for field1 to field20 in the answer method?

Comment: @jasonfungsing No you don't. In this case you're setting the default behaviour of your mocked object. In fact, if you call `doReturn(...).when()` you'll override this default behaviour with new custom stub. So it's useful if you need to change the behaviour of one method while others will still return the defaults. BTW, I've updated my answer.

Comment: You can also just do
`mock(ObjectNeedToMock.class, RETURNS_DEFAULTS);`
No lambda needed.

Comment: For a simpler implementation and Mockito's own answer to this question, see https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#14

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in the result of `getField1()` to `getField20()` in a particular test case, you shouldn't mock it at all. In other words, if all the specific test case should be concerned about is `getTheImportantInt()`, then your test case should look like this:

```
@Test
public void testMethodNeedToTest() throws Exception {
      ObjectNeedToMock o = mock(ObjectNeedToMock.class);
      when(o.getTheImportantInt()).thenReturn("1");

      // test code goes here
}
```

Comment: I have modified my example, I do need to do something with the field1 to field20, however this is something not be care within the test method.

Comment: Well, then it depends. If what you do with field1 to field20 affects the result you're checking in the test, you have no choice but to mock the values. Otherwise, you can still ignore them, after all, all you're interested in testing is not affected by it. On a different note, if you have a class with 20 getters, you should really consider improving your design (even if it's an entity class, it's probably worth redesigning the DB table to contain fewer columns, as long rows in SQL DBs impair performance dramatically in most DBs).

Comment: I am feeling lucky that this 20 getters object is a json response mapping class from a 3rd party restful api call :-)

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you have no real options other than mocking the whole thing. If you don't really care about the values, you can take the approach in the other answer and define default values. If you do, you might be better off with a helper method that will create a mock and stub each of its methods with a value you provide as a parameter to the helper method. In other words, instead of 20 `when` lines of code, you'll have a single method call to the helper method with 20 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin users:

```kotlin
    val mocked: MyClassToMock = Mockito.mock(
        MyClassToMock::class.java,    

        object:Answer<Any> {
            override fun answer(invocation: InvocationOnMock?): Any {
                if (String::class.java.equals (invocation?.method?.getReturnType())) {
                    return "Default answer for all methods that returns string"
                } else {
                    return Mockito.RETURNS_DEFAULTS.answer(invocation)
                }
            }
        }
    )
```