# How to return the same mock from fluent interface methods

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, fluent

Let's say I have the following code:

```
public class OuterClass {

    @Inject
    InjectedClass injected;

    public void method() {
        injected
            .methodA()
            .methodB()
            .methodC();
    }
}
```

And the following test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OuterClassTest{

    @InjectMocks
    OuterClass outer;

    @Mock
    InjectedClass injected;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        outer.method();
        verify(injected).methodA();
        verify(injected).methodB();
        verify(injected).methodC();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell Mockito to return the same mock from each method call of `InjectedClass`? I tried using `@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)` but in that case, Mockito seems to return a new mock from each method call. This means that `verify(injected).methodA()` will pass, but it won't pass for `methodB()` and `methodC()`, because they were called on a different mock.

Currently I have to have a `setUp()` method like this:

```
when(injected.methodA()).thenReturn(injected);
when(injected.methodB()).thenReturn(injected);
when(injected.methodC()).thenReturn(injected);
```

... which is ugly and anoying. Do you know a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154657/mockito-mock-all-methods-call-and-return

Comment: Perhaps a design issue, where `InjectedClass`'s `methodA`, `methodB`, and `methodC` should be private, with a public method such as `doStuff` that delegates to the private methods.  Then `OuterClass` calls a single method, and simplifies the test.